# Sharepoint 2010 - Dynamically add new fields in edit or new forms

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm looking to get some guidance with Sharepoint 2010. I am working on a project which requires a system that would inform concerned users of an outages with their applciation and provide regular updates via email (worflow).

I can accomplish most of the tasks with a simple custom list and workflow. Users would be able to input their start/end time of the outage, description and their update. With a workflow an email would be sent to the concerned users with all the details.

Where the problem starts is that, we have to provide hourly updates on an outage. So I would need to be able to add new update fields dynamically for every new updates and then be able to send all the updates via an email workflow.

At the moment I am just trying to figure out the best way to go about this. I tought that a simple custom list would be sufficient but looks like ill need to create a more complex system. Perhaps ill need to create 3 custom lists, 1 master list that would gather the details from list 1 (cotnains the description, start/end time) and the list 2 (contains updates) and some how link the together.

Would anyone have any advice about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create 2 lists: 1 main with all details and another one with updates and added multi lookup field to the first list. 
OR even better - 

added lookup field to the second list and when item is created - set lookup to the item in the list 1. Then you would be able to get all items from the list 2 (updates) by the item in the list 1.
Hope it makes sense.
Regards,
Andrey.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider having following 4 fields apart from whatever you need right now.
1. Update 
2. Outage (choice yes/no)
3. Previous updates (hide it on Edit form)
4. latest update hidden (hide this on edit form)

I would use one list. Let the workflow run whenever a new item is created or an existing item is updated.

For new Outage items send the outage email.

For updates:
Every hour check for update on the item

If there is any update then copy the value to latest update and previous updates. Clear the value of update column.

Send email with latest update value.

Once outage is over user updates the update field and makes outage over to yes.

At this point of time the workflow is complete.